# Saving Site as a Template SP 2013

Tags: 2013

We are in the process of setting up a new 2013 farm.

We have some PS scripts that will build it out similar in structure to our old 2007 build.

We are trying to build a template site for intitial roll out to pre-populate the sites with some Apps (i.e. calendar, etc.).

Started with the initial Site Collection and learned the hard way about the Publishing Infrastructure piece.

Created a new Site Collection based off of the Team Site.  I am guessing Publishing is turned off by default in 2013.  Verified Publishing was not on at the Site Collection or Site level.  The page opened fine.  I went into settings, Save Site as a template is available.  Nothing has been added to site.  However, I get the "Sorry, something went wrong."  I tried to do it via "_layouts/15/savetempl.aspx", a suggestion from Google, and it did not work.

Tried the above only with a Community Site and it did not work either.

Checked the features turned on at the Web Application level and nothing screams turn me off.

Is there a nerd knob I missed?  Most GoogleResearch focuses on the Publishing Aspect of it.

Comment: Are you able to see anything in the logs?  It sounds like a permissions issue to me

Comment: Additional testing, created a BlankSite via powershell and got another middle finger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW.

It turned out to be the STIG requirement of having FIPs enabled.  Once we disabled FIPs, we were able to Save Sites as a Template as long as it was a clean site without Publishing Infrastructure being turned on.